# The usage of the word "chance" in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Context: "But it was a **chance** stumbling upon a run-down, yet functional, laboratory in his late grandfather's home that solidified the young man's enthusiasm for chemistry."

Could you give me some explanations, please? Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an **adjectival** use of the word ***chance*** - which is normally a noun.

A "chance encounter", for example, is one that has been unplanned, or was unforeseen. It simply happened "by chance". So a "chance stumbling upon a run-down laboratory" is something that could not have been predicted, and was not arranged in any way. It was a fortuitous event which simply happened.

The OED explains the adjectival ***chance*** in the following way, with the examples shown.

> That occurs or is by chance; happening to be such; casual, incidental.
>   (Often unnecessarily hyphened.)
>
> 1676   in Court Leet Rec. Manch. (1888) VI. 15   John Sherdley Butcher
>   for sellinge of two chance cowes vis. viiid.
>
> 1722   D. Defoe Jrnl. Plague Year 10   My Dealings were..not by a Shop
>   or Chance Trade.
>
> 1732   True & Faithful Narr. in J. Swift Misc. III. ii. 255   There
>   were five chance Auditors.
>
> 1833   H. Martineau Tale of Tyne i. 2   The chance amusements of
>   former days.
>
> 1860   W. Collins Woman in White iii. i. 427   I parted with my chance
>   companion.
>
> 1868   I. Saxon Five Years Golden Gate 181   Chance gains.
>
> 1883   ‘G. Lloyd’ Ebb & Flow II. 77   A chance paragraph in a book.

Comment: In this particular example, _stumbling upon_ already suggests it was a chance discovery, so the additonal use of _chance_ is almost redundant.

Comment: @KillingTime Quite right. The word "chance" is perhaps a duplication, simply included to give emphasis to "stumbling upon".